# 'I would like [something]' sounds half-baked; is preposition 'to' necessary there?

Tags: prepositions, complementation

I've heard and observed many saying...

> I would like a cup of coffee 
>  I would like our website to be responsive 
>  I would like a customer care button at the bottom of the webpage 
>  and so on...

I always feel that it's a half-baked sentence and it *strongly* requires  ***'to + have'***

> I would like ***to have*** a cup of coffee
>  and so on...

Do we require '*to*' after *'would like....'* to sound a complete sentence? Or is it okay without 'to'?

Comment: I remember that you often use learner's dictionaries and *Practical English Usage* (PEU). Have you looked it (*would like*) up? Would the definitions and explanations still make you feel that it's half-baked?

Comment: The problem with it is I don't remember such an entry *and* I have no access to my notes from PEU! @DamkerngT. Ah, will be happy if you enlighten me with the entry.

Comment: Okay, a moment! -- It's under PEU 325.6 *would like*. (325 is like: verb). I also found *would like* in both [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/would-like) and [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/like_2). I'm not sure if this is one of the learner's dictionaries you usually use.

Comment: @DamkerngT. oh, it's transitive + no passive as well. That says it all...thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not really sure that it really can't be used passively, though I can say that I've never seen or heard *would like* being used passively before.

Comment: @snailboat okay, added two lines as you *missed* the title of the question that talks about my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The third one needs an article "*a* customer care button" but otherwise these are perfectly idiomatic and not "half-baked".  **would like** can take a noun-phrase (*a faster car*), an infinitive-phrase (*to know her name*), a noun-phrase complemented by an infinitive phrase (*Sheila to relocate to London*).